# Android BroadcastReceiver and Activity.onPause()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The documentation for BroadcastReceiver [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, 
>       you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). 
>       (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary 
>       system overhead).

I made an example of Activity A1 that has an inner BroadcastReceiver that updates A1 interface when a Service S1 makes a sendBroadcast. S1 spends around 8 seconds to finish.

When running A1 and hitting the home button for making A1 call onPause, "it still receives the intent from sendBroadcast" and updates the interface, am I missing something or the documentation is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Did you call unregisterReceiver in onPause?

Comment: have you also declared the intent filter in manifest?

Comment: what do you mean by making A1 call onPause

Comment: the unregisterReceiver usually called in onDestroy

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen: nop, i call it on onDestroy().

Comment: @StinePike: I declared de intent filter at code level inside onCreate()

Comment: @Bolton: I have A1 in foreground and after pressing a button i fire my service. As the service needs around 8 secs to finish, i hit "home" button and that calls the onPause() method of A1

Comment: @3h3: Thats what im doing dude, anyway ive seen that many places said that it should be done onPause() althought doing that you can miss more easily the sendBroadcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document meant to say that if you unregistered in onPause() then you won't receive broadcast intents when paused. If you do not unregistered then you would continue to receive broadcast intents. You unregistered in onDestroy(), but when the home key is pressed only onStop() is called and onDestroy() will not be called. Thus you continue to receive broadcast.