# Do dynamically registered BroadcastReceivers survive component/app death?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

What implications has a failure to unregister a dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver in an activity ? Will <del>it run</del> its `onReceive()` be called even after the activity is destroyed (ofc if a broadcast matching its intent filter is fired) ? Even after the process is killed ?

---

Related ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html))

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(), because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history stack.

So does that mean that BRs *are only active till onPause runs* (if registered in an activity) <del>as my off hand experiments in gingerbread suggest</del> (they were off hand indeed) - or that *if* I unregister *then* I won't receive intents (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503977/android-broadcastreceiver-and-activity-onpause)) ?

**EDIT**: actually I [posted](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63975) this as an issue for the documentation

Answer (score 2):

> What implications has a failure to unregister a dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver in an activity ?

I suspect there may be a few possible outcomes but that would depend on what the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered to do and whether it is a stand-alone class or an inner class of the `Activity`.

> Will it run even after the activity is destroyed ?

It's not clear what you mean by "run". Technically a registered `BroadcastReceiver` isn't 'running' purely as a result of being registered. Effectively registration is simply a case of putting a 'hook' into the Android messaging system with the `onReceive(...)` method being a callback. If there is a broadcast which matches the `BroadcastReceiver's` intent filter then it's 'running' life is from the start to the end of the call to `onReceive(...)`.

> Even after the process is killed ?

No. As all components of an Android application run in a single process (with a few exceptions such as out-of-process `Services`), once the process is killed, the `BroadcastReceiver` will be killed with it.

> So does that mean that BRs are only active till onPause runs (if registered in an activity)...

As I mentioned above, a `BroadcastReceiver` is only 'active' during it's `onReceive(...)` method life - at other times, it isn't instantiated and is simply in a 'registered' status.

> ... or that if I unregister then I won't receive intents (as said here) ?

Again, as I mentioned above, registration is simply telling the OS that the receiver wishes to receive notifications (broadcast) that match an intent filter. If it is unregistered then the system removes the 'hook' (callback) for that particular `BroadcastReceiver` class and hence it won't be instantiated and passed the relevant `Intent`.

Comment: "I suspect there may be a few possible outcomes but that would depend on what the BroadcastReceiver is registered to do and whether it is a stand-alone class or an inner class of the Activity" -> that's the most important part of the question really - there must be dome docs on what happens on failure to unregister

Comment: "It's not clear what you mean by "run"." -> will onReceive be called ? _even after process death_ - but for one thing after activity garbage collected